# redirect url using route function in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have local site and in that site I have integrated wordpress + codeigniter.

Now I have a blog and custom query to fetch posts from wordpress database using wordpress `wp_query` function, everything is working pagination is also working but I'm having a small issue that if I type my blog address without a trailing `/` than the pagination doesn't work properly

1) When I use:

```
  siteaddress/blog/
```

it works just fine and pagination also work like:

```
  siteaddress/blog/page/1
  siteaddress/blog/page/2
```

I can move forward and backward properly

Only problem came when I open url

```
 siteaddress/blog
```

than the pagination url becomes

```
siteaddress/blogpage/1
siteaddress/blogpage/2
```

It means missing 1 trailing `/` between blog and page so can I solve this issue using codeigntiers route?  I already tried:

```
$route['blog'] = "blog/page/$1";
```

and

```
$route['blog'] = "blog/";
```

these both methods couldn't solve my problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

live version for my site is:

```
aws.chemfreecom.com/blog  or aws.chemfreecom.com/blog/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog/ [R=301,NC,L]
```